# Get default browser User-Agent

Tags: c++, qt, browser, user-agent

In my application I make a few POST requests. I would like to simulate the client default browser user-agent because some websites make the most absurd checks.

Right now I just have a static one like this:

```
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0");
```

How can I make this dynamic?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: @LaszloPapp The application should make requests with the same User-Agent of the default browser that the user has installed.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I'm not sure if it is worth it. All the solutions I came-up with involve opening the default browser, wish wouldn't be good. Just looking for some ideas. OS, mainly Windows.

Comment: You could probably do some eavesdropping as the last resort, at least, but that is not a "nice" way of doing it. :)

Comment: What is your idea? :)

Comment: Having a daemon listening at the traffic in the background, and parsing this information out of the ongoing html traffic. Then, you could query this from your daemon. But really: what happens if you open up the default browser or you do not support those weird sites, or just do similarly how other browsers do?

Answer (score 3):

Can you use windows API **ObtainUserAgentString**?

```
HRESULT ObtainUserAgentString(
   _In_   DWORD dwOption = 0,
   _Out_  LPCSTR *pcszUAOut,
   _Out_  DWORD *cbSize
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775114(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Interesting. I will test it and get back.

Comment: Looks like this only works to get really old Internet Explorer user agent strings, not the user agent of the user's current default browser.